# Arcscene 3D.wrl file to interactive 3D pdf

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, 3d-model, geopdf

I want to create an interactive 3D PDF for my customer from my 3D data in ArcScene, which seems easy in principle but is becoming an odyssey.

I would like to know if someone have any easy solution for this issue, or if know any freeware player to visualize arcscene 3D models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Adobe Acrobat Pro DC or Adobe InDesign you can import *.u3d or *.prc format in PDF. You can use 3D features interactively with these formats in PDF.

1. Export your scene in "VRML" format. In Arcscene => File => Export scence => 3D
2. Change *vrl to *u3d using [meshlab](http://www.meshlab.net/) software. It's a free software.
3. Import *u3d format to a pdf file using Adobe Acrobat pro DC or Indesign.

If you want to present an animation in a PDF:

1. Create an animation in Arcscene.
2. Convert it to *.MP4 or *.GIF file, then import file to a PDF using Adobe Acrobat pro DC or Indesign.

Comment: Sorry I didn´t explained me well, I want to create an interactive 3D pdf, not an animation.

Comment: @JuanCordoba Please update your question to make what you are asking clearer.

Comment: Thanks so much, I found an issue with meshlab but I have solved, this is the solution if you have this error message 'Missing converter executable 'C:/Program Files/VCG/MeshLab/plugins/IDTFConverter.exe' https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues/33